# How can I run a html file from terminal?

Tags: html, linux

I have a html file that titled `test.html` this is the file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="document.getElementById('saveForm').click();">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart-form-data" name="my_form" onsubmit="clearTextBoxCounter()" action="http://xxxxx" >

  <input type=hidden name=teks value=><center><b>KIRIM SMS GRATIS</b></center><br><br>
Nomer HP:<br />
  <input class="field text small" type="text" maxlength="20" name="Phonenumbers" value="085642383165"/>
  <br />

<br />
Isi Pesan:<br />
  <textarea rows="5" cols="20" onKeyPress=check_length(this.form); onKeyDown=check_length(this.form); name=Text >testing pesan 2</textarea>
<br />

<input id="saveForm" class="btTxt" type="submit" value="KIRIM" name="TOMBOL" />

</body>
</html>
```

as you can see when the file is loaded it automatically clicks the submit button, and redirects it to `http://xxxxxx` how can I run this html file from terminal? I'm using this on openwrt with webserver installed on it.

Comment: not familiar with openwrt, doesn't it have lynx (the command line browser)?

Comment: Start researching headless browsers. Picking one for you and walking you through installing one up is out-of-scope for this site.

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to do this. You should describe your actual problem for us, because writing an entire HTML document with embedded JavaScript for automatically submitting the form, just to programatically issue POST requests from the command line, is the worst solution to that problem. There's probably a one-line CURL command that can do this for you.

Answer (score 65):

For those like me, who have reached this thread because they want to serve an html file from linux terminal or want to view it using a terminal command, use these steps:-

1. **If you want to view your html using a browser**:

Navigate to the directory containing the html file
If you have chrome installed,

Use

```
google-chrome <filename>.html
```

Or Use

```
firefox <filename>.html
```

2. **If you want to serve html file and view it using a browser**

Navigate to the directory containing the html file
And Simply type the following on the Terminal:-

```
pushd <filename>.html;  python3 -m http.server 9999; popd;
```

Then click the I.P. address 0.0.0.0:9999 OR localhost:9999 (Whatever is the result after executing the above commands). Or type on the terminal :-

```
firefox 0.0.0.0:9999
```

Using the second method, anyone else connected to the same network can also view your file by using the URL: `0.0.0.0:9999`

Comment: this is the fastest way IMHO to get what I wanted.

Comment: Other users in the network can access said webpage if they navigate to `<your-machine-ip>:9999`.  The `0.0.0.0` IPv4 address is a placeholder for `INADDR_ANY`  as seen on [this manage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html). Its meaning roughly being: "let the server listen on every interface on the machine". You can obtain your machine's IPv4 address if you issue `ip addr` on linux machines, `ifconfig -a` on BSD systems (such as macOS) or `ifconfig /all` on Windows boxes.

Comment: What is the purpose of &lt in this context? Could someone please explain?

Comment: @AMS it stands for the < (less than) sign. It meant <filename>.html

Answer (score 30):

This works :

```
browsername <filename>
```

Example: `google-chrome index.html`

[image]

Answer (score 20):

You could always use [the Lynx terminal-based web browser](http://lynx.browser.org/), which can be got by running `$ sudo apt-get install lynx`.

With Lynx, I believe the file can then be viewed using `lynx <filename>`

Comment: Lynx will not execute the JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

Skip reading the html and use `curl` to POST whatever form data you want to submit to the server.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to view a html file from terminal using lynx or links. But none of those browswers support the onload javascript feature. By using lynx or links you will have to actively click the submit button.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is simply this.

Open the terminal

Navigate to the directory containing the HTML file

And simply type: browse (your file name) without the parentheses of course.

This will run your HTML file in Firefox browser.

Answer (score -2):

You can make the file accessible via a web server then you can use curl or lynx

Comment: Why not just on the client side ? -_-

Comment: Would be a long line of curl code. Webserver is simpler and easier to debug

Answer (score -3):

You can open an HMTL file from Linux/Unix terminal by using Firefox `<filename>.html`.

Answer (score -4):

`python -mhtmllib test.html` or `curl http://www.comanyname.com/somepage.html|python -mhtmllib -`

Comment: Add some explanation

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".