# Capture the image in background and save in folder in PHP

Tags: php, html

Capture the image in the background and save it in a folder in PHP.

I have created a PHP page in which we capture the image of an HTML using html2canvas() and via ajax save that image in a folder.
When I run the code from the browser it shows an HTML and saves the image in a given folder. (Here it is working fine).

**The issue is when I run the same file using cmd like via PHP cmd or via CRON (php test.php) then that is not generating an image just render HTML in the terminal.**
[image]
**How I run the same code in the background and save in the generated image in a folder?**

test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" id="capture">Capture & Save</button>
<div class="parent-wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper-box" id="canvas" width="1080" height="1080">
      <div class="heading">
        Lorem Ipsum
      </div>
      <div class="sub-heading">
        Lorem ipsum , Lorem
      </div>

      <div class="paragraph">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>

      <div class="bottom-heading">
        #Lorem
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function truncate(source, size) {
  return source.length > size ? source.slice(0, size - 1) + "..." : source;
}
var para = document.querySelector('.paragraph');
var res = truncate(para.innerHTML, 280);
para.innerHTML = res;
</script>


<script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('.movable_div').on('contextmenu', function(){
    return false;
  });
  
  $('#capture').click(function(){
    div_content = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    html2canvas(div_content, {
      dpi: 96,
      width: 1080,
      height: 1080,
    }).then(canvas => {
      data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1);
      save_img(data);      
    });
  });
  // Onload Click capture
  $('#capture').click();     
});
  
//to save the canvas image
function save_img(data){
  //ajax method.
  $.post('save_jpg1.php', {data: data}, function(res){
  });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

save_jpg1.php

```
<?php 

//just a random name for the image file
$random = rand(100, 1000);

$savefile = @file_put_contents("output/$random.jpg", base64_decode(explode(",", $_POST['data'])[1]));

//if the file saved properly, print the file name
if($savefile){
    echo $random;
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Tried below code also but not work for me:

```
setTimeout(function(){
      div_content = document.querySelector("#canvas");
      html2canvas(div_content, {
        dpi: 96,
        width: 1080,
        height: 1080,
      }).then(canvas => {
        data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1);
        save_img(data);      
      });
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: Your script uses relative paths.  Are you expecting the files to be saved in $HOME/output/ ?  If not, cd into the right directory.  Update your code with error handling.  Test with `at now` which gives you a similar (but not identical) environment as cron.

Comment: I also tried with /var/www/html/img/output/$random.jpg" path but when I run via terminal it's render HTML. How I trigger script button click via terminal.

Comment: So you want to start a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser from your crontab and access a particular page?

Comment: I have tried 1 cmd but using --headless but that also renders HTML code on the terminal. Any other solution.

Comment: Useful
Source http://phptutorial.info/learn/create_images/#code6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using below library.
**Source:** https://github.com/stil/gd-text

Wrote the script in **PHP** and **run** via **terminal** to create image in background.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal doesn't know how to render an html file like a browser does - the terminal will simply output the html as a text file.  I think there may be a way to programmatically trigger such a rendering, and you could update the javascript to trigger the html2canvas when the page loads rather than after a click.  In that way, you could trigger it from the command line, it would render, and fire the save function with the image.

Looks like this might have some ideas for how to run an html file from the terminal:

[How can I run a html file from terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760105/how-can-i-run-a-html-file-from-terminal)

Specifically, you may want to try serving the html file locally, and triggering a browser view

Comment: When javascript triggers it's finding the particular id of that div, how that process works in the terminal. 
The goal is to trigger happens and 1 ajax run to save the image in the folder.

Is there any other way I achieve this?